# Why prestashop have installations problems on Centos 7

Tags: prestashop, centos7

[image]

I have some problems with installation PrestaShop on Centos 7.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this error is pretty clear, you should check all your folder permissions, especially /var/cache, more details:

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/installation/localhost/#setting-up-file-rights